# Conjecture: For $a,b,c,A,s$ the sides, area, and semi-perimeter of a triangle, and $x\ge2$: $a+b-c\ge s(2/3)^{(x+1)/(x-1)}(\frac{3^{3/2}A}{s^2})^x$

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, algebra-precalculus, inequality, triangles

In the comments of this [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4680040/is-this-a-stronger-form-of-the-triangle-inequality), it was mentioned that the RHS and LHS were expressions in $a,b$ and $c$ so the inequality was not useful. So I wanted to find an improved triangle inequality where for a given RHS, the LHS there are infinitely many possible combinations of $a,b$ and $c$.  I obtained following conjecture obtained by empirical means and verified for discrete $2 \le x \le 70$. Can this be proved?

> **Conjecture**: Let $a,b,c$ be the sides of a triangle of area $A$ and
> semi-perimeter $s$. Then, for any $x \ge 2$,
>
> $$ a+b-c \ge s\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{\frac{x+1}{x-1}}
> \left(\frac{3^{\frac{3}{2}}A}{s^2}\right)^x \tag 1 $$

For a given area $A$ and semi-parameter $s$ there are infinitely many possible values of $a,b$ and $c$ hence the above inequality is gives an explicit lower bound of the triangle inequality.

**Question 1**: Is the conjecture true?

**Question 2**: If true, can the inequality be improved?

**Note**: The difference between LHS and RHS for random $2 \le x \le 70$ was typically or the order of $10^{-8}$ or smaller if $a,b$ and $c$ were the sides of a triangle inscribed in a unit circle.

**Update 13-5-2023**: For $x \ge 5.23$ experimental data shows that the triangle inequality can be improved to

$$ a+b-c \ge s\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{1 + \frac{2}{x}}
\left(\frac{3^{\frac{3}{2}}A}{s^2}\right)^x \tag 1 $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some thoughts for the conjecture**:

Using Ravi's substitution $a = u + v, b = v + w, c = w + u$ for $u, v, w > 0$, we have
$$a + b - c = 2v, \tag{1}$$
and
$$s = \frac{a + b + c}{2} = u + v + w \tag{2}$$
and
$$A = \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)} = \sqrt{(u + v + w)uvw}. \tag{3}$$

The desired inequality becomes
$$2v \ge (u + v + w)\left(\frac23\right)^{(x+1)/(x-1)}\left(\frac{27uvw}{(u + v + w)^3}\right)^{x/2}. \tag{4}$$

Using $uw \le \frac{(u+w)^2}{4}$, it suffices to prove that
$$2v \ge (u + v + w)\left(\frac23\right)^{(x+1)/(x-1)}\left(\frac{27v(u + w)^2/4}{(u + v + w)^3}\right)^{x/2}. \tag{5}$$

Letting $y = \frac{2v}{u+w}$, it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{2y}{y+2} \ge \left(\frac23\right)^{(x+1)/(x-1)}\left(\frac{27y}{(y + 2)^3}\right)^{x/2}. \tag{6}$$
or (taking logarithm)
$$f(y) := \ln \frac{2y}{y+2}
- \frac{x+1}{x-1}\ln \frac23 - \frac{x}{2}\ln \frac{27y}{(y + 2)^3} \ge 0. \tag{7}$$

If $x = 2$, (7) becomes $\ln\frac{(y+2)^2}{4} \ge 0$ which is true.

If $x > 2$, we have
$$f'(y) = \frac{xy - x + 2}{y(y+2)}.$$
Let $y_0 = (x - 2)/x > 0$.
We have $f'(y_0)  = 0$,
and $f'(y) \le 0$ on $(0, y_0)$,
and $f'(y) \ge 0$ on $(y_0, \infty)$.

Thus, we have
$$f(y) \ge f(y_0) = \ln\frac{2(x-2)}{3x-2}
- \frac{x+1}{x-1}\ln \frac23 - \frac{x}{2}\ln \frac{27(x-2)x^2}{(3x-2)^3}.$$
It suffices to prove that, for all $x > 2$,
$$\ln\frac{2(x-2)}{3x-2}
- \frac{x+1}{x-1}\ln \frac23 - \frac{x}{2}\ln \frac{27(x-2)x^2}{(3x-2)^3} \ge 0.$$

To be continued.

Comment: @NilotpalSinha There is a typo: The denominator of the last one is $(3x-2)^3$.

Comment: OK. With the typpo correction, Wolfram Alpha says the minimum of the last inequality for $x > 2$ is $0.0003286$ which would settle the inequality with a strict $> 0$ showing the there is still some scope for improving the lower bound of the triangle inequality. I have added an update in this direction in the original post and I can see how your derivation here can be modified to obtain the optimal form of the triangle inequality https://bit.ly/3BFwb09

Comment: @NilotpalSinha I think that it is not easy to prove the last inequality.

Answer (score 2):

*Remarks*: We can find the minimum of $a + b - c$ given $s, A > 0$ with $s^4 \ge 27A^2$.
This minimum is given by $2u_1$
where $u_1$ is the smallest positive real root
of $su(s-u)^2 - 4A^2 = 0$.

Using Ravi's substitution $a = x + y, b = y + z, c = z + x$ for $x, y, z > 0$, we have
$$a + b - c = 2y, \tag{1}$$
and
$$s = \frac{a + b + c}{2} = x + y + z \tag{2}$$
and
$$A = \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)} = \sqrt{(x + y + z)xyz}. \tag{3}$$

**Fact 1**: There exist $x, y, z > 0$ such that
$x + y + z = s$ and $\sqrt{(x+y+z)xyz} = A$ if and only if
$s, A > 0$ and $s^4 \ge 27A^2$.
(The proof of Fact 1 is given at the end.)

By Fact 1, our problem is to find the minimum of $2y$
subject to $x, y, z > 0$; $x + y + z = s$ and $(x+y+z)xyz = A^2$, given $s, A > 0$ with $s^4 \ge 27A^2$.

To this end, we need the following auxiliary result.

**Fact 2**: Given $s, A > 0$ with $s^4 \ge 27A^2$,
the cubic equation $su(s - u)^2 - 4A^2 = 0$
has three positive real roots $0 < u_1\le s/3 \le u_2 < s < u_3$.
(The proof of Fact 2 is given at the end.)

By Fact 2, let $u_1$ be the smallest positive real root
of $su(s - u)^2 - 4A^2 = 0$.

We claim that the minimum of $2y$ is given by
$2u_1$ when $x = z = (s - u_1)/2$ and $y = u_1$.

*Proof of the claim*: First, using $zx \le (z + x)^2/4$, we have
$$A^2 = (x+y+z)xyz \le sy \cdot \frac{(s - y)^2}{4}. \tag{4}$$

Second, using $su_1(s-u_1)^2 - 4A^2 = 0$, we have
$$0 \le sy(s-y)^2 - 4A^2
= sy(s-y)^2 - su_1(s-u_1)^2$$
$$= s(y - u_1)[(s - y - u_1)^2 - yu_1]. \tag{5}$$

Third, if $y < u_1$, then by Fact 2, we have $y < u_1 \le s/3$
and $s - y - u_1 - \sqrt{yu_1} > 0$ which contradicts (5).

Thus, we have $y \ge u_1$. Also, when $x=z=(s-u_1)/2$ and $y = u_1$, we have $2y= 2u_1$.

The completes the proof of the claim.

---

*Proof of Fact 1*:

“only if part”: Using $xyz \le (x + y + z)^3/27$,
we have $27A^2 \le s^4$.

“if part”: Let us prove that
there exist $x, y > 0$ such that $2x + y = s$ and $s x^2y = A^2$. Using $x = (s-y)/2$,
we have $sy(s-y)^2 -4A^2 = 0$.
Let $F(u) := sy(s-y)^2 - 4A^2$.
We have $F(0) = -4A^2 < 0$ and $F(s/3) = \frac{4}{27}s^4 - 4A^2 \ge 0$.
Thus, there exists $y_0 \in (0, s/3]$ such that $h(y_0) = 0$. Thus, $x = (s-y_0)/2, y = y_0$
satisfy $x, y > 0$, $2x + y = s$ and $sx^2y = A^2$.

Thus, $y = y_0, x = z = (s - y_0)/2$
satisfy $x,y,z>0$, $x + y + z = s$ and $(x + y + z)xyz = A^2$.

We are done.

---

*Proof of Fact 2*:

Let $h(u) := su(s-u)^2 - 4A^2$.

If $27A^2 = s^4$, then $h(u) = -\frac{1}{27}s(4s-3u)(s-3u)^2$.
Thus, $h(u) = 0$ has three positive real roots $s/3, s/3, 4s/3$.

If $27A^2 < s^4$,
noting that
$f(0) = -4A^2 < 0, f(s/3) = 4s^4/27 - 4A^2 > 0,
f(s) = -4A^2 < 0$,
$h(u) = 0$ has three positive real roots
$0 < u_1 < s/3 < u_2 < s < u_3$.

We are done.

Comment: Could please share/add any reference to fact 1 and 2 in your answer to make it self contained?

Comment: @NilotpalSinha I edited it accordingly.